# Object[] to Class[] in Java

Tags: java

Is there any built-in Java6 method (perhaps in lang or reflection?) for performing:

```
private Class[] getTypes(final Object[] objects) {
    final Class[] types = new Class[objects.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        types[i] = objects[i].getClass();
    }
    return types;
}
```

Which takes an Object array and returns an array containing the type of each element?

Comment: As far as I know, that is the best way to go about it in Java.

Comment: That `for(..)` loop could be replaced with `for (Object o : objects)` which improves readability *(but then you'd have to count the index separately, hrm :) )*. But yeah, this is basically the way to do it in Java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there's no built-in facility for this in JavaSE.

Not much of a burden, surely, it's easily unit-testable and only a few lines.

If you really wanted something you don't write yourself, there are various 3rd-party libraries that will do it for you (e.g. Apache Commons Lang's `ClassUtils`, CGLIB's `ReflectUtils`), so if you already have one of those, you can use them.

Comment: ClassUtils, not ObjectUtils I think :)

Comment: I ended up using *ClassUtils.toClass*. One less method for me to maintain. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In JDK - no. There is in [apache commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/):

[`ClassUtils.toClass(Object[] objects)`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/ClassUtils.html#toClass%28java.lang.Object[]%29)

But writing it yourself isn't painful at all.

Answer (score 1):

I think [lambdaj](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/) has features for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no better way to do that.
However, I don't think it matters much. You already packaged your code as a reusable method. If you need to use it from several distinct classes just turn into a public static method in some utility class.

Once you've done that then, for all practical purposes, you have a convenient way for converting ab array of object into an array of classes. In other words, if you already implemented a certain service in a reusable way, then you effectively extended your toolkit. It does not matter that this specific service is not part of "standard" JRE.